# Vertical CSS Divider Color

Tags: html, css

So I saw this http://cre8tivenerd.com/demos/css/Line-separator.html and wanted to create a divider with that "pressed" effect. The problem is, I don't have a clue of what the divider colors should be for me, tested it out and it didn't get the same effect. My background color is #222222. Anyone that can help me and maybe explain how I "calculate" which colors I should use for the divider?

Comment: This is more a design issue...anyway, in this case I would use a [hr element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-hr-element.html#the-hr-element)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get this effect like this:

```
<div class="vDivider"></div>
```

css:

```
.vDivider {
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #434343;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

The contrast between the background color and the bottom border creates this effect.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/DxuPu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It won't look good as #222 is already too dark. Only option as @Dim13i suggested is using black as bottom color, but it won't look distinct.

How about make it a little thicker?

```
.line-separator {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #777;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    height: 2px;
}
```